# Unable to connect to MySQL database using MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So completely new to OOP, so apologies in advance. I am trying to connect to my database. Keep getting the following error message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

If anyone could help, this would be a massive help.

```php
$GLOBALS ['config'] = array(
  'mysql' => array(
    'host' => ' 127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'db' => 'honeybee'
  ),
  'remember' => array(
    'cookie_name' => 'hash',
    'cookie_expiry' => 604800
  ),
  'session' => array(
    'session_name' => 'user'
  )
);

try {
      $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
       die($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Where (according to the comments)....

```php
<?php 
class Config { 
   public static function get($path = null) 
   { 
     if ($path) { 
        $config = $GLOBALS['config']; 
        $path = explode('/', $path); 
        foreach ($path as $bit) { 
           if (isset($config[$bit])) { 
              $config = $config[$bit]; 
           } 
        } 
        return $config; 
     } 
     return false; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: We can't help if you don't tell us anything about the Config class. It must be defined somewhere in your code otherwise it would have failed before getting to the point of trying to resolve the hostname.

Comment: <?php
class Config {
  public static function get($path = null) {
    if ($path) {
      $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
      $path = explode('/', $path);

      foreach ($path as $bit) {
        if (isset($config[$bit])) {
          $config = $config[$bit];
        }
      }
      return $config;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

Comment: Do you think it is throwing an error because of the host name?

Comment: I think your config class is not doing what you expect - take it out and test it in isolation.

Comment: That `$config` path traversal is maybe a bit overcomplicated, and is probably overwriting a variable at an inopportune moment.

Comment: You have a space prefixing the IP address in your config `mysql/host` property. Remove that

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski There's nothing _technically_ wrong with that `Config` class ~ https://3v4l.org/cImhO

Comment: @Phil Correct, I just tested it out. Well spotted, on the IP leading space.

Comment: I removed the space before the IP: this brought up a different error. Then tried replaced the IP address with 'localhost' and and it worked. Cheers guys.